# Deleting unused Models, stale content types prompt

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am removing an unnecessary table and model from our Django website. I have removed all foriegn key references before the migrations.DeleteModel(...) is called, but I still am receiving the following prompt when I run the migration:

> The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:
>
> ```
> myapp | MyDeletedModel
> ```
>
> Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
>   be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types? If
>   you're unsure, answer 'no'.
>
> ```
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
> ```

I am confused why I am receiving this prompt is there a way I can stop this prompt from showing when we go live? we use a CI environment where we do not have users available to answer "yes" or "no"

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The contenttypes framework contains references to model tables. In this case, you have a stale reference to the table you just deleted. It is perfectly safe to answer `yes` and remove the stale contenttype. It would be a different story if you renamed a table that had a `GenericForeignKey` pointing to it, in which case other objects would have a `ForeignKey` to that `ContentType`, and the delete would cascade along those relations.

In a live environment, you can pass the `--noinput` option to suppress this prompt. However, it will default to `no`. It's usually not really a problem to have some stale `contenttypes` lying around.

Comment: Thanks @knbk, I will check with our ci guy to see how we run the migrations for --noinput, if we answer this once, will it remember the answer, or will we be prompted every migration?

Comment: You'll be prompted every time you run a migration that renames or removes a model.

Comment: ok, I am looking at the django_contenttype table. I no longer see a row for the table when I answered yes. but If I answer no, it will prompt the next migration, right?

Comment: sorry, last question I SWEAR! I found the documentation about --noinput, and was able to see that we ARE using it. HOWEVER, what does the system answer when I use this option? from what I understand, would the system answer yes?

Comment: The system is quite conservative if you use the `--noinput` option. For contenttypes, it would always answer `no`.

Comment: I have a problem: each time I run "migrate", it asks for it, even if I dont touch anything.

Comment: I would test what this actually do before doing with this with real data. This thing just dropped a table that was important to us. Luckily, in a test databse.