# Any disadvantage in removing a model's content type after removing the model in a Django application?

Tags: django, django-models

I understand from other answers around this topic, removal of a model via migrations do not automatically remove its remnants including the content type entries for the model unless you answer 'yes' to the prompts to do so or not use --noinput option. While it is understandable the Django is conservative and leaves that control to the developers, I want to know if there is any other benefit in leaving in the content type entries of removed models. I could only see disadvantages since there are a bunch of collateral content hanging around such as in auth.Permission. Over a period of time my apps may develop a content fat.

Please note my question is only about the content type removal and what I might be missing out if I removed entries there. Aka, what is the thing that Django folks had in mind to decide to keep its content intact by default when a model is removed other than want to be conservative in general for cleanups.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540714/2395796) might help.

Comment: I read that earlier. Per that "...safe to remove the stale content-type...but not a problem to have some stale content-types around..". But I wonder if there is any real use for keeping such content-types around. Foe instance, such as for audit. But increasingly it appears to me there is no real value in keeping the stale content types. Thanks.